# Slice columns in several parts Spark(1.5.2)-Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have an RDD greater than 22 columns (therefore, I cannot transform it to a Dataframe in order to make the filtering) with 10 columns and I want to obtain a second dataframe with the columns 3 to 4 and the range of columns 7 to 10. In order to obtain the range from 7 to 10, I use the slice function the following way:

```
var aux = rdd.map(_.slice(7, 10))
```

My problem comes when trying to join this interval with the interval from 3 to 4. I have seen that slice method only accepts one range. Is there any way to skip this limitation in order to obtain in a single variable both ranges?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
rdd.map(row => row.slice(3, 4) ++ row.slice(7, 10))
```

Comment: You cannot use the placeholder `_` twice. You must do something like `rdd.map(row => row.slice(3, 4) ++ row.slice(7, 10))`. Also, beware that `slice` does not include its last index: `_.slice(3, 4)` only keeps the index `3`.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about performance, but you can do something like this:

```
rdd.map(l => ((3 to 4) ++ (7 to 10)).map(l(_)))
```

Comment: It returned an error message in l(_) as it expected a String and it tells it finds an int, but with the operator ++ and two slices I was able to solve the problem.